# What does the MSP430 cmp.b instruction do?

Tags: msp430

Working on the microcorruption challenge. Coming in from a little experience with MIPS and I'm still figuring out some msp430 things.

The instruction set summary doesn't have a particularly descriptive entry for the cmp.b instruction, but I can see that it is being used here in conjuction with the jne instruction. The jne description:  Jump to Label if Zero-bit is reset.

```
455a:  f290 8500 1024 cmp.b #0x85, &0x2410
4560:  0720           jne   #0x4570 <login+0x50>
```

So the cmp.b is comparing the byte (as indicated by the .b suffix) of the 0x85 immediate with whatever byte value is stored in the address 0x2410, but then I can only imagine this sets a bit in some register reserved for the jne instruction (aforementioned Zero-bit) to examine in order to know whether or not it should execute the jump? If this is the case which register would that be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The User's Guide says:

> **Description**
>   The source operand is subtracted from the destination operand. This is accomplished by
>   adding the 1s complement of the source operand plus 1. The two operands are not
>   affected and the result is not stored; only the status bits are affected.
>
> **Status Bits**
>   N: Set if result is negative, reset if positive (src ≥ dst)
>   Z: Set if result is zero, reset otherwise (src = dst)
>   C: Set if there is a carry from the MSB of the result, reset otherwise
>   V: Set if an arithmetic overflow occurs, otherwise reset

The status bits are stored in the status register, which is called `SR` or `R2` (if you need to access it (which is not the case here)).

And `JNE` means "jump if not equal", so all those details do not matter for understanding it.

Answer (score 1):

I cant comment atm to other users answers due to to low reputation but i think the following information regarding the JNE command may be useful for other users in regards to [CL.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55895017/8298187)'s comment.

**JNE/JNZ** are instructions which cause the controller to **jump to the given label if the zero bit is not set**. In this case the controller would jump to #0x4570 <login+0x50>

This is described in *slau144j MSP430x2xx FamilyUser's Guide p. 59.*